# Insert data into core db table

Tags: magento-1.9, database, setup-script, install-script

I need to run this SQL query on Magento, but since I have a multi-tenant solution, it need to be done through Data/Install scripts as it will run every time a new client comes in.

What should I use? Data or Install scripts? And should I use DDL or normal SQL?

Here is the query:

```
`INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`,
`attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`,
`frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`,
`is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES(140, 3, 'thumbnail', NULL,
 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'image', 'Thumbnail
 Image', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```